# Issue with "Product Prices" reindex data magento 1.9.0.1

Tags: magento-1.9, price, reindex

I had updated the products by import.
Once i had done the import, there is reindex needed with product catelog data and Product Prices, once i had done the reindex for "Product Prices".

particular products which are linked with category getting error

There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

I don't know, what is exactly happening.

detailed view of the error

```
a:5:{i:0;s:25:"Image file was not found.";i:1;s:4381:"#0 /home2/valuepl5/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Image.php(163): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Image->setBaseFile('/m1a2_military_...')
#1 /home2/valuepl5/public_html/demo/app/design/frontend/default/ma_sahara_fashion5/template/catalog/product/list.phtml(176): Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image->init(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), 'rotator_image')
#2 /home2/valuepl5/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home2/valuepl5...')
#3 /home2/valuepl5/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#4 /home2/valuepl5/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#5 /home2/valuepl5/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#6 /home2/valuepl5/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#7 /home2/valuepl5/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('product_list', true)
#8 /home2/valuepl5/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Category/View.php(90): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('product_list')
#9 /home2/valuepl5/public_html/demo/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/category/view.phtml(70): Mage_Catalog_Block_Category_View->getProductListHtml()
#10 /home2/valuepl5/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home2/valuepl5...')
#11 /home2/valuepl5/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/base/d...')
#12 /home2/valuepl5/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#13 /home2/valuepl5/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#14 /home2/valuepl5/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#15 /home2/valuepl5/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#16 /home2/valuepl5/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#17 /home2/valuepl5/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#18 /home2/valuepl5/public_html/demo/app/design/frontend/default/ma_sahara_fashion5/template/page/2columns-left.phtml(67): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#19 /home2/valuepl5/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home2/valuepl5...')
#20 /home2/valuepl5/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#21 /home2/valuepl5/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#22 /home2/valuepl5/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#23 /home2/valuepl5/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#24 /home2/valuepl5/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#25 /home2/valuepl5/public_html/demo/app/code/local/Magentothem/Layerednavigationajax/controllers/CategoryController.php(127): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#26 /home2/valuepl5/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Magentothem_Layerednavigationajax_CategoryController->viewAction()
#27 /home2/valuepl5/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#28 /home2/valuepl5/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#29 /home2/valuepl5/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#30 /home2/valuepl5/public_html/demo/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#31 /home2/valuepl5/public_html/demo/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#32 {main}";s:3:"url";s:25:"/index.php/r-c-tanks.html";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:2:"en";}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are been given the reason.

`a:5:{i:0;s:25:"Image file was not found.";i:1;s:`

Use google and search for: 'magento "Image file was not found."'

Check your imported products. There is an issue with setting the product images in you import.